# Increase number of RESULTS_RECOGNITION in speech recognition android

Tags: android, speech-recognition

i want to make google speech recognition flexible enough to give me ten to fifteen results while matching voice..

```
 // This are the intents needed to start the Voice recognizer
            Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
           // i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                 //   RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something");
```

i want to increase number of `results` given below. it normally give me four or five..

```
ArrayList<String>  results = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

is it possible ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. As of API level 19 you can set the upper limit by setting [EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS) when calling the `RecognizerIntent`. But there is no `EXTRA_MIN_RESULTS` to set the lower limit.

Comment: i have checked it.. it is giving me only 5 results . i want to increase it.

Comment: and this is for minimizing results

Comment: He just told you it's not possible, and that this parameter only sets the maximum, not the other way around.